# How to check if a cell is composed of one word or not with `IF`

Tags: excel

I have nams of colors in each cell of Column A. Most are one word, but some are two words.

Example:

```
brown
light brown
dark brown
```

I'm trying to filter the data in Excel to only display colors with 2 words using a simple `IF` statement. I was thinking to use the code below, combined with a `SEARCH` for the space (`" "`) between two words to display `"No"` in Column B next to the respective cell in Column A.  However, what I tried does not work.  All of the 3 rows display `"No"`, which means it couldn't find the space between two words, or maybe it interprets `" "` as a blank cell, not a space.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1," ")), "Yes", "No")
No
No
No
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you've got the arguments of `SEARCH` reversed, see examples [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495). Try `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",A1)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: thanks @MichaelChirico.  It worked!

Comment: I would suggest a slight change to `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",TRIM(A1))),"Yes","No")` This way if there is a space on the start or end of a single word result it will report it as "No" correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, you may be better off using the [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)  function to accomplish your goal:

```
=if(countif(A1,"* *"),"Yes","No")
```

(I admittedly stole this from [here](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=251571) & haven't tested it because the syntax appears to be slightly different on LibreOffice.)

Comment: Thanks.  You've already resolved my problem in your first comment. Marking this as answer now.